# Preventing users from accessing a site on mobile

Tags: responsive-design, mobile-web, empty-state

We have a situation where we develop a very complex data platform and we don't support mobile version of the web app for a reason. Nevertheless, we have a native mobile app that supports most of our functionalities.

The main issue is we had to disable the login on our website, in order to prevent users from landing on a broken page, but there are several ways they can achieve it and it is a problem. So my idea is to bring login back, but show an empty screen that proposes to either use a desktop device for the best experience and/or download our app, since I don't want to lose valuable mobile leads.

Is there a better approach? I am not fully confident about that at the moment and am still researching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show all mobile web users an "Open in the app" banner, and make the rest of the screen (on any webpage) a simple message that your platform is not yet supported on mobile web. It sounds like there is no reason why users should ever see a login on mobile web, so don't let them try it and expect that the site will work after login.

Comment: Thanks, actually you are right, after a couple of discussions with our team we've figured out what you just said. Maybe we shouldn't mislead them with the login on mobile.